# How to compute this angle form integral?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be the curve in $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $x^2/9+y^2/4=1$ with counter-clockwise orientation. Compute $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$$

I guess that the answer should be $2 \pi$ since the form equals $d \theta$, but I'm not sure how to state this rigorously.

First of all, how to show $\dfrac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}=d\theta$? If I let $\theta= \arctan(y/x)$, differentiation would work but it is not defined for $x=0$.

Also,  to compute $\int_{\gamma} d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\theta'(t)dt=\theta(2\pi)-\theta(0)$. But if I use the above definition of $\theta$, it has only values in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so I cannot say $\theta(2\pi)=2\pi$.

So how can explain nicely about $\theta$ and $d\theta$?

Comment: First of all, $\gamma$ as defined above is not a curve but a set of points instead.  To evaluate the given integral you'll need a parametrization of that set.  Depending on that parametrization the integral may take any value in $2\pi\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Green's theorem?

Comment: Try parameterizing the curve in the following way, and apply this method to your integrand; $x=3 \sin \theta$, $y=2 \cos \theta$

Answer (score 1):

First, the Pfaffian  $\theta$ is defined by
$$\theta=\frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}.$$
You want to compute $\int_{\gamma}\theta$. For that purpose you *need* a parametrization of $\gamma$, say $\gamma(t)=\bigl(3\cos(t),2\sin(t)\bigr)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.  Then evaluate the integral $\int_{\gamma}\theta$, which is by definition
$$\int_{\gamma}\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\theta_{\gamma(t)}\bigl(\dot c(t)\bigr)\,dt.$$
Work out from here obtain the (obvious) result $2\pi$.